# Compiling com.parse:parsefacebookutils leads to com.parse.Parse Class not found exception

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm currently trying to add Facebooklogin capabilites to my App.

According to the Android Docs, when I add

```
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
```

To my Build.gradle it should include the entire com.parse.Parse, com.parse.ParseObject... classes already. So I removed the compile for the normale parse-android and now my dependencies look like that:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
//compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3' //Already include in parsefacebookutils
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

//NOTE: I do not actually have anything in my 'libs' folder.

BUT after doing so my Applicationclass (and every other Class) can't find the com.parse.Parse stuff. And the com.parse namespace only contains the 'ParseFacebookUtils' class.

#### I already tried:

compiling the 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3' in the dependencies, which only leads to the expected 'DexError' when deploying.

---

Removing the @aar at the end, which imported the com.parse namespace correctly, but lead to the Gradle error. I assume because the facebookutils have the parse-android:1.10.3 as dependency in their maven project. (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.parse/parsefacebookutils-v4-android/1.10.3)

```
Warning:Module 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like there is a bug in the parsefacebookutils that is loaded. I can't say what it is but work around is that download the latest jar files and use them instead of loading.

Parse-1.11.0
ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.3

those .jar files in library directory and remove the compile rows from build.gradle.

at least I'm getting forward with this.